# Issue with transactionreceipt deprecated in iOS 7 warning

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, ios7

I am going to update my application for iOS 7 and I am using IAP , but xcode 5 give me this this error :

> transactionreceipt is deprecated : first deprecated in iOS 7

here is my code :

```
// saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk
    - (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
    {
        if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kProductIdentifier])
        {
            // save the transaction receipt to disk
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
```

how can I fix this issue ?

//EDITED :

I used my AndreyMan's answer but nothing happened  and compiler gave me APP:requestProductData END message

```
- (void)requestProductData
{
       [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];

    NSLog(@"IN-APP:requestProductData");
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                 initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject: @"com.compony.product"]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];

    NSLog(@"IN-APP:requestProductData END");


}
```

and then gives me these messages :

> ```
> 2013-10-08 14:26:21.400 Arta[1138:60b] Purchasing... 2013-10-08 14:26:28.380 Arta[1138:60b] Unknown Reason. 2013-10-08 14:26:28.383
> ```
>
> Arta[1138:60b] Purchase faild...

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Purchase compelete...");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Purchase faild...");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Restore compelete...");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"Purchasing...");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}




- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        // error!
        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
        if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorClientInvalid) {
        }
        else if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentInvalid) {

        }
        else if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed) {
        }
        else if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
            // [self showAlert:@"In-App Purchase" withMessage:@"This device is not allowed to make the payment."];
            NSLog(@"User Cancellation.");
        }
        else {
            // SKErrorUnknown
            NSLog(@"Unknown Reason.");
        }
    }
    else  {
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}
```

Comment: See the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573). Receipt validation is different in iOS 7.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry I don't get it !! would please give me a sample or something ?

Comment: Go to the Apple developer forums and search for receipt validation. There are plenty of discussions and code references.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt;
receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];
```

Comment: Thanks but does not connect with App store ! would you please check my edited question ?