# Pass NSData transactionReceipt with SKPaymentTransaction to verify receipts in iOS7

Tags: ios

So my apologies in advance for the simplicity of this question, I am not a pro with iOS, but learning as I go!

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out a way to verify receipts properly with my app (a digital magazine). I've found some [open source code](http://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/verify-the-transactionreceipt-of-skpaymenttransaction/) that looks good and I think will fit perfectly into my app, but I need some help understanding this line in particular:

"All you have to do is to pass the NSData transactionReceipt of an instance of SKPaymentTransaction to this class and wait for the response to come back."

What does that look like exactly in terms of code, and in terms of iOS7 [now that transactionReceipt is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009268/issue-with-transactionreceipt-deprecated-in-ios-7-warning)? At this point I understand the visual code and how to tweak it a lot more than anything else, and that's all I really need to get going. Once I understand what that means I can tweak it to make it fit into my app, which is fully functioning and only missing receipt verification. (It already knows when the subscription has been purchased and will unlock accordingly. It just doesn't know when/if that subscription has expired or not.)

The actual source code for receipt verification I'm using [can be found here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32143863/iOSAndOSX/SKTransactionReceiptVerifier.zip). If anyone has anything easier to use I'm all ears!